# Clay Sanskrit Library and Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, sanskrit

I am not fully sure whether this is the most appropriate site to ask this question. If it is not, please suggest a more proper one.

I am currently learning sanskrit and have been meaning to acquire a paper version of Mahabharata and some other books. In doing so, I have stumbled across the [Clay Sankrit Library](http://claysanskritlibrary.org/volumes_current.php). It seems to have been a great project (it is said that it dissolved a few years ago), but I cannot tell whether they managed to print everything they set out to print.

Hence, my questions are as follows (in no particular order).

1. What is a good way to purchase Mahabharata and other works in hardcover paperbacks in good print, but without them being rare collector's editions?
2. How are Clay's books? Is the print quality good?
3. Is Clay's collection complete? That is, if one purchases it, will he have the complete Mahabharata or will something be missing?

Much appreciated.

Comment: If I were you, I would not buy the Clay's collection, because it is not the critical edition.

Comment: What would you buy?

Comment: I would buy critical edition translation. One translation is available by Debroy but its accuracy is doubtful. Another partial translation of some parvas is available by University of Chicago Press, but it has some peculiarities and is expensive.

Comment: What if I am in it for sanskrit? Is there a good edition without translation?

Comment: If I knew Sanskrit, I would have directly purchased the BORI edition. I dont know if the BORI is still publishing the books or if they are out of print. In any case, they are also available online.